# Sensor Data Tap From PLC/Scada Server

Tags: plc, scada

This is a newbie question .. Is there a way to sniff out sensor packet data from the SCADA environment? Any suggestions to proceed?

Comment: You need to provide much more information. What SCADA environment? Are you using OPC? If so, which OPC? Modbus? Where to you want to get the data? Are you literally trying write a protocol decode that is listening on an Ethernet? Etc.

Comment: It is yokogawa PLC and I suppose SCADA server too. Is it possible to get the sensor values getting to PLC into our own tap/sniffer? If yes, is this common practice?

Answer (score 3):

In general the answer is "yes, there is a way of getting data out of your PLC." The mechanics of the way will depend on your environment. The SCADA server may have an OPC interface for querying things. The PLC will likely have some protocol interface where you can query things, for example using Modbus.

How to proceed: Read the documentation for your PLC and your SCADA environment and see what interfaces you have available.

Comment: Thanks Janm, I will read thru the documentation for PLC & SCADA. This leads me to another question. One way of gathering data would be to connect into PLC or SCADA server. Another way could be to bring in a tap or sniffer in the environment. Are you aware of example as how one introduce this tap?

Comment: @VaibhavKhanduja In principle it is very similar to implementing the protocol. If you wanted to monitor Modbus traffic, for example, you would add a station on the RS485 line for serial, or a device on the Ethernet to listen to the traffic an decode the protocol. The difference is that you listen to both sides of the protocol and interpret the traffic instead of implementing one side and asking for what you need.